# SeleniumPython3.x How can i handle this element?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to enter text in this element and want to choose the suggested element that is coming up. send_keys("text") is not working with this element and throwing exception "ElementNotInteractableException". Can anyone please suggest how can i handle this element?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Customer/Create")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(2)

#now when i am sending keys to below element it is throwing the exception:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap'])[1]").send_keys("your")
```

i am not able to proceed further with  this as it throws exception. Please suggest how can i enter the text in it and the suggestion option that comes with it, how can i select one of it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried sending the text to the `input` element inside that `div`? `(//div[@class='k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap'])[1]//input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the text to `input` element inside that `div` instead of the `div` itself.
`(//div[@class='k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap'])[1]//input`

Comment: woked, and with that able to select the suggested option inside it as well. Thanks.